# Override parent CSS Rule of 'overflow:hidden'

Tags: jquery, css

I am display thumbnails on a `div` with overflow:hidden as its style attribute.

When I click one thumbnail, I replace the image with its larger view (which creates a zoom effect) but since some of the images are quite big, it gets cut off by its parent division.

So, I want that particular thumbnail to defy its parent rule and get out and show its `100%self`.

---

<sup>*The main reason for me, to bump this question, is to get/provide a good working solution.* The best one is found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450801/295264).</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and more efficient method to do this, was to add the following property to the image to get the job done.

> position: absolute

After it has absolute positioning, its jumps out of its container till it finds another relative container, thus defying its parent rule.

I am created a simple demo <sup>*[[here]](http://jsfiddle.net/xa79e/2/)*</sup> to illustrate this situation and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've tried modifying the element css via jquery on click?

```
$(this).css('overflow', 'visible');
```

Just use jquery to revert the css modification when you clear the magnified image.

If that doesn't work for you for some reason or another, you could create a hidden div for magnified images.  Use jquery to create a click event that changes the source and displays the div that contains different css attributes.  Again, hide that div with the clearing click event.

Comment: `$(this).css('overflow', 'visible');` will not work as I am trying to do this on the parent. I was thinking about what you said afterwards, but I will try to see if this is possible.

Comment: Did you try: `$(this).parent().css('overflow', 'visible');`

Answer (score 0):

ideally, **the div should have no width and height** declared (meaning: let the content decide it's dimensions)

```
$('div_selector_here').on('click',function(){

    //try one of the following:
    //they both stretch the div to the image IF it has no width and height declared:

    // if width and height are declared for the div, this will leak the image out of the container
    $(this).css('overflow','visible'); 

    //if width and height are declared for the div, this will add scrollbars
    $(this).css('overflow','auto'); 

});
```

additionally, you can add this to make sure the image is snug in the div (and again, it's idea you don't set width and height to the div):

```
img{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
```